# How to bypass shared hosting upload_max_filesize?

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, file-upload

I am running a file hosting site and am limited to my hosts 128MB maximum file size. I tried to modify the `.htaccess` file with:

```
php_value max_execution_time 1200
php_value max_input_time 1200
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
php_value post_max_size 1024M
```

But this did not change anything. I should throw in here that I do not have root access and the hosting provider I am using is Hosting24.

Comment: The simple answer is, you can't. Or, at least, you shouldn't.

Comment: Why is this such a issue on web hosting?

Comment: The whole point of shared hosting is that it is cheap. When you put a lot of users on as few servers as possible you need to set some limits on what people are allowed to do... imagine if everyone was allowed to do whatever they wanted; the shared hosting would be useless at worst, and unreliable at best. Upload limits is just something the provider has had to make a decision on. As far as shared hosting goes, 128MB is not that shabby, actually. Many shared hosting providers set it much lower than that.

Comment: What are my options then if I need more upload data?

Comment: Use the [contact form](http://www.hosting24.com/contacts.php) on your provider's website.

Comment: I did that. Are VPS servers a good option?

Comment: Then wait for your provider to respond. VPS servers are a good option if that is what you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible unless the web host allows you to modify the `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ini set programatically;

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1024M');
```

You need to do that config in `.htaccess` like;

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

Some hosting provider can deny this setting on their server. So, this may not solve your problem.

```
upload_max_filesize
```

is a `PER_DIR` configuration, means you cannot change it by usşng `ini_set`. Please [refer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) here for more detail

Comment: In the `custom_size` part i would add my max size?

Comment: Why do they not allow files to upload that are larger than 128MB?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

Create a new file called **'.user.ini'** and put your variables in it like this;

```
max_execution_time=1200
max_input_time=1200
memory_limit=128M
upload_max_filesize=1024M
post_max_size=1024M
```

Now upload this file to hosting root (i.e. public_html)

Also you can try to create **'php.ini'**, put same above code in it and upload it to hosting root (i.e. public_html)